# How do I fit the select2 multiselect field for the whole page?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf, jquery-select2

I'm trying to build a nice multiselect with thymeleaf and Select2. The data is transmitted by Thymeleaf and a multiselect with all data is created. The Select2 works only conditionally.

Using style="width: 100%" in  tag, the problem has not been solved. It might be attached to bootstrap or something else.

```
[...] //Other Code
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <label for="sektor">Sektoren</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <select id="sektoren" class="select2_multiple" multiple="multiple" name="sektoren[]"  th:field="*{sektoren}" size=4>
     <option th:each="sektoren : ${konfigForm.sektorenArray}" th:value="${sektoren}" th:utext="${sektoren}"></option>
    </select>
  [...] //Some Code for the Info-Modul Button (working fine)
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem, the select field does not extend over the whole page. The values are listed vertically and the whole field is compressed.

Snipped of the Multiselect: https://www.imagebanana.com/s/1520/oTJHdnFw.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.content-article{
    max-width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I put the style="width: 100%" in the wrong Select Tag. Now its working fine.